How do I use Clang's attribute `preferred_name`?
Clang has a non-standard attribute preferred_name that is used e.g. in libc++ to spell std::basic_string<char> as std::string (which is more user-friendly).
I'm trying to use it for my own types, but it doesn't seem to work: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/re4af1Pej
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

template<typename T> struct my_basic_string;
using my_string = my_basic_string<char>;
template<typename T> struct __attribute__((__preferred_name__(my_string))) my_basic_string;

int main()
{
    foo<std::string>(); // std::string
    foo<my_string>(); // my_basic_string<char>   -- But why not `my_string`?!
}

Note that this must be tested on Clang, with -stdlib=libc++ (libstdc++ doesn't have this annotation, and prints std::basic_string<char> instead of std::string).
Am I getting the syntax wrong? I believe I'm doing the same thing as libc++ does: [1], [2].

I don't understand yet why this snippet doesn't work. I was not aware of that preferred_name attribute. I tried to use on my code base on the complex BaseUnit template class and it worked! At least on debugger, some names like BaseUnit<double, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0> are now seen as Distance.

This appears to be a Clang bug, which I've now reported here.
The attribute doesn't work unless you use the target type in a specific way somewhere in the TU. For example, adding using X = my_basic_string<char>; somewhere below the attribute fixes it (... = my_string; doesn't work though). Defining this class and declaring a variable of type my_string (or my_basic_string<char>) also fixes it.
I've created a macro that automatically applies this workaround (and also disables the attribute on compilers that don't support it):
run on gcc.godbolt.org
MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS( (template <typename T> struct), my_basic_string,
    (my_string, my_basic_string<char>)
    (my_wstring, my_basic_string<wchar_t>)
)

#include <type_traits>

#define MY_IDENTITY(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define MY_END(...) MY_END_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define MY_END_(...) __VA_ARGS__##_END

#define MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS(type_, name_, aliases_) \
    MY_IDENTITY type_ name_; \
    MY_END(DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_USING_A aliases_) \
    DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS(type_, name_, aliases_)

#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_USING_BODY(name_, ...) using name_ = __VA_ARGS__;
// Adding `MY_IDENTITY()` here to keep the legacy MSVC preprocessor happy.
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_USING_A(...) DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_USING_BODY MY_IDENTITY()(__VA_ARGS__) DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_USING_B
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_USING_B(...) DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_USING_BODY MY_IDENTITY()(__VA_ARGS__) DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_USING_A
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_USING_A_END
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_USING_B_END

#if defined(__has_attribute)
#if __has_attribute(__preferred_name__)
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS(type_, name_, aliases_) \
    MY_IDENTITY type_ \
        MY_END(DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_ATTR_A aliases_) \
        name_; \
    DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_CLANG_WORKAROUND(aliases_)

#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_ATTR_BODY(name_, ...) __attribute__((__preferred_name__(name_)))
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_ATTR_A(...) DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_ATTR_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_ATTR_B
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_ATTR_B(...) DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_ATTR_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_ATTR_A
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_ATTR_A_END
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_ATTR_B_END

#ifdef __clang__ // Workaround for bug: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/106358

#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_CLANG_WORKAROUND(aliases_) \
    MY_END(DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_TOUCH_A aliases_)

#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_TOUCH_BODY(name_, ...) static_assert((void(std::type_identity<__VA_ARGS__>{}), true));
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_TOUCH_A(...) DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_TOUCH_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_TOUCH_B
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_TOUCH_B(...) DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_TOUCH_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_TOUCH_A
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_TOUCH_A_END
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_LOOP_TOUCH_B_END

#else // no workaround needed
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS_CLANG_WORKAROUND(aliases_)
#endif

#else // this attribute is not supported
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS(type_, name_, aliases_)
#endif

#else // no __has_attribute
#define DETAIL_MY_CANONICAL_TYPEDEFS(type_, name_, aliases_)
#endif


https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xrq6qj333

@MarekR Well yes, as I said "Defining this class and declaring a variable of [this] type ... also fixes it." But this isn't viable for arbitrary classes (requires definition, requires the constructor to be constexpr), that's why the macro does something else.

This was just cleaner way to demo your workaround. This complex macro is to noisy to demo problem (I get it in real code this macro is preferred). Here is better workaround.
